# How does one solve the following system of equations in two variables?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations in $R$ and $m$ for fixed $k>0$ and $l\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$ 
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
k&=\frac{R}{m^2+R^2}, \\
l&=\frac{m}{m^2+R^2} 
\end{aligned} \right..
$$
Is there a method to solve this system of equations? I tried rewriting the first equation to a quadratic one in the variable $R$ in order to use the quadratic formula. But that didn't really get me any closer to the solution, I think.

Comment: Yes, you can multiply by $m^2+R^2$ to obtain two polynomial equations. Using the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) you can solve it. If you want, I can write out the solution. More easily, multiply the first equation by $l$ and the second by $k$. This yields $km=lR$. Then substitute $m=\frac{l}{k}R$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24k%3D%5Cfrac%7BR%7D%7Bm%5E2%2BR%5E2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24l%3D%5Cfrac%7Bm%7D%7Bm%5E2%2BR%5E2%7D%24&p=1), there's the quite similar [Find the value of $x +y$](/q/3215584), where its answers provide several approaches you can use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the value of $x +y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215584/find-the-value-of-x-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that one has $ml+Rk=1$ and $mk=lR$ from the two given expressions. Now one can solve the system of simultaneous equations.